# Branch Remote from other computer

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have installed SourceTree on my iMac. I have one project on this computer. But, I want have to access from my MacBook pro. The computers are in the same network, but I don't know how to make this...

Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume that the repository path on your iMac is shared within your network.

As long as you have access to the repoisoty it should be fairly easy to add it as an remote on your MacBook Pro.

The following commands need to be executed on the command shell on your MacBook Pro though:

```
cd <path where you want your repository>
git clone /network/path/to/the/project/on/your/iMac/
```

And you should be done. Now you can push and pull changes like you are used to.

**NOTE** Usually you would set up a `bare` repository as a remote and use that on your iMac and on your MacBook. A `bare` repository only contains the git history and no working tree (means no checked out files), so you can not work directly on a `bare` repository.
You could place this `bare` repository on a shared network path for easy access.

To create a `bare` repository from your old project you can use `git clone --bare` like this.

```
git clone --bare /path/to/project/ /shared/network/path/
```

Hope that helps.